# How to fix slow boot after adding M2 NVME after Grub menu?

Tags: boot, nvme, m2

After adding an M2 NVME drive, the boot **between the Grub menu and the Ubuntu login** takes 1m and 25s, instead of about 10s before adding the M2. Ubuntu Mate 22.04 up to date.

Ubuntu is not installed on the NVME. In the bios, the SSD with Ubuntu is selected to boot, but the slow start is after the Grub menu.

The NVME works fine in Ubuntu and Windows, speed in line with expectations.

Edit4: [Video captured with accelerated passage during the pause](https://drive.proton.me/urls/TM8Y6KZH1M#nUL5C4UksF4d)

Edit1: Bios is set to boot the drive with Ubuntu (not the NVME). Just after validate to start Ubuntu at Grub menu, the process make a pause during one minute and 25s with no output. Then, the classic commands lines appears, then 10s after the login of Ubuntu is displayed. The drive NVME works fine in Ubuntu and Windows, speed compliant to expected. The slow is only just after Grub and before login.

Edit2: the boot before Grub menu is fast. The freeze is coming just after validate the entry on Grub menu. The journal is creating after the freeze.

The logs do not show this duration, which I measured with a stopwatch.

My pc and Ubuntu starts up without crashes or errors, only that it takes 8.5 times longer than before.

I thought it was linked to the M2's GPT type, but I formatted it with an MBR table and there's the same problem.

Full reports, logs, boot-info, fstab and UUID:
https://pastebin.com/Czy2rjnZ

Can you help me to fix this slow boot of Ubuntu please ?

```
------systemd-analyze blame-------
graphical.target @8.454s
└─multi-user.target @8.454s
  └─virtualbox.service @8.403s +50ms
    └─network-online.target @8.398s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.864s +6.533s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.345s +477ms
          └─dbus.service @1.334s
            └─basic.target @1.322s
              └─sockets.target @1.322s
                └─snapd.socket @1.307s +12ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.269s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1.074s +194ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @969ms +93ms
                        └─local-fs.target @959ms
                          └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @7.223s
                            └─run-user-1000.mount @6.887s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @387ms
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @343ms +42ms
                                  └─systemd-sysusers.service @293ms +49ms
                                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @284ms +6ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @272ms
                                        └─-.mount @265ms
                                          └─-.slice @265ms
-----ls -l /var/crash--------
total 0
-----lsblk -fe7--------
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                                   
├─sda1      ext4   1.0   UBUNTU   ee2f4425-cb03-4ffe-a80f-3cfb5ef81775   26,6G    50% /
└─sda2      ext4   1.0   MyDocs   4bea60a1-932c-40c0-82b5-31622fc3fabc  141,6G    58% /media/home/MyDocs
sdb                                                                                   
├─sdb1      ntfs         Windows  062FDE8B0C7254F8                                    
├─sdb2                                                                                
├─sdb5      ntfs         WinTools 157BC523529514C4                      269,1G    21% /media/home/WinTools
└─sdb6      ext4   1.0   Backup   a539ecdd-74c8-4264-a43f-386a774a516d                
sr0                                                                                   
nvme0n1                                                                               
└─nvme0n1p1 ntfs         2To      A61E44541E441FA3                        1,5T    18% /media/home/2To
-----cat /etc/fstab--------
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=ee2f4425-cb03-4ffe-a80f-3cfb5ef81775 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=4bea60a1-932c-40c0-82b5-31622fc3fabc /media/home/MyDocs auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=157BC523529514C4 /media/home/WinTools auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=A61E44541E441FA3 /media/home/2To ntfs nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: If you mean /dev/nvme.. device Check uuid in /etc/fstab for It. This does not Match with lsblk Output.

Comment: Do not use MBR. The only place for MBR(msdos) is if you have a system from before 2012 and have to install Windows in BIOS boot mode. Did you update NVMe drive's firrmware? And is UEFI firmware the latest version, also? Also some NVMe ports conflict with SATA ports. Or only one works. Check your motherboard manual and make sure you are not trying to use conflicting ports.

Comment: Ubuntu is not installed on that NVME. It's UUID is right is fstab. MBR or GPT, same effect (tried both). Bios is set to boot on the drive with Ubuntu (not the NVME). The pause appears just after validate to start Ubuntu on Grub menu, pause for one minute 25s, then commands line are displayed.

Comment: Did a Windows update turn fast startup back on, so then mount of NTFS partitions as read/write fails? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Even if you have turned fast start up off, Windows updates may turn it back on. And Windows updates are often in background, so you are not totally aware they have occurred.

Comment: @oldfred : please read entirely the thread.

Comment: I have had slow boot where partition could not be correctly mounted. It takes 90 seconds to time out. Also same issue when I do not unmount a partition correctly on shutdown.I suspect timeout on mount issue. But you should be able to see issue in logs. Have you checked logs?

Comment: Video added. @oldfred : logs shared, take a look, no trace of the freeze